# Site loads on iPad/Chrome but not on iPad/Safari

Tags: ios, azure, ipad, safari

iPad version : 16.7.7
When I tried loading one of my sites on the mentioned iPad's Safari I go this error saying
"Failed to load resources : Server responded with 404"

But when I load the site on the same iPad's chrome, it loaded.

Although I initially suspect this seems to deployment related issue, what are other aspects I should be looking at for this scenario.